# My Javascript function is not being called

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm trying to learn how functions work in Javascript. This is supposed to be a function to output user messages. When I click on my 3 buttons nothing happens. What am I doing wrong? Thanks guys.

```js
function buttonReport(buttonId, buttonName, buttonValue) {
    var userMessage1 = "Button id: " + buttonId + "\n";
    var userMessage2 = "Button name: " + buttonName + "\n";
    var userMessage3 = "Button Value: " + buttonValue + "\n";
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="id1" name="Left Hand Button" value="Left" onclick="buttonReport(this.id, this.name, this.value)"/>
<input type="button" id="id1" name="Center Button" value="Center" onclick="buttonReport(this.id, this.name, this.value)"/>
<input type="button" id="id1" name="Right Hand Button" value="Right" onclick="buttonReport(this.id, this.name, this.value)"/>
```

Comment: please provide more code or context, the code provided works as expected.

Comment: You function is missing some sort of notification I.E. `console.log` or `alert` so when you run your function you have no idea if anything happened, take a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/z3chkprd/

Answer (score 5):

You are not doing anything with those variables:

```
function buttonReport(buttonId, buttonName, buttonValue) {
      var userMessage1 = "Button id: " + buttonId + "\n";
      var userMessage2 = "Button name: " + buttonName + "\n";
      var userMessage3 = "Button Value: " + buttonValue + "\n";
      console.log(userMessage1, userMessage2, userMessage3);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function is being called but does not actually out put a message or send it anywhere... try the following.

```
<script>
function buttonReport(buttonId, buttonName, buttonValue) {
  var userMessage1 = "Button id: " + buttonId + "\n";
  var userMessage2 = "Button name: " + buttonName + "\n";
  var userMessage3 = "Button Value: " + buttonValue + "\n";

 alert(userMessage1);
 alert(userMessage2);
 alert(userMessage3);
}
</script>
```

That will make the function actually create a javascript alert on to the page instead of just loading 3 functionally scoped variables into memory.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, you are not outputting your messages once they are built. I.e. you build them like this:

`var userMessage1 = "Button id: " + buttonId + "\n";`

but then you do nothing with the variable containing the message. So, you could display them to console like this:

`console.log(userMessage1);`

Or, to show it to the users like this:

`alert(userMessage1);`

By the way, you could also reduce the number of parameters to your function and pass the button object itself, kind of like this:

`onclick="buttonReport(this)"`

and then your function can get all necessary values from it, like this:

```
function buttonReport(btn) {
  var userMessage1 = "Button id: " + btn.id + "\n";
  var userMessage2 = "Button name: " + btn.name + "\n";
  var userMessage3 = "Button Value: " + btn.value + "\n";

  console.log(userMessage1 + userMessage2 + userMessage3);
}
```

One of the reasons you'd want to do this is for maintenance reasons.  Say later you want to display two values only (or four, or one) instead of three, you only need to change your code in your one place (the function) instead of all places the function is being called.

**See running demo below**

```js
function buttonReport(btn) {
  var userMessage1 = "Button id: " + btn.id + "\n";
  var userMessage2 = "Button name: " + btn.name + "\n";
  var userMessage3 = "Button Value: " + btn.value + "\n";

  console.log(userMessage1 + userMessage2 + userMessage3);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="id1" name="Left Hand Button" value="Left" onclick="buttonReport(this)" />
<input type="button" id="id2" name="Center Button" value="Center" onclick="buttonReport(this)" />
<input type="button" id="id3" name="Right Hand Button" value="Right" onclick="buttonReport(this)" />
```